# never ending loop for user populated arraylist

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to write a method to take user input car specs and add them into an ArrayList. This needs to accept any amount of specs the user wants to input, including none.
This is my first post here, so apologies for any poor syntax.

```
public static ArrayList getTrim() {

Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter car trim");
ArrayList<String> trim = new ArrayList<>();

while (t.hasNext()) {
trim.add(t.next());
}

return trim;

}
```

I thought this condition would return false if whitespace was entered. This continues iterating and can only be exited manually.

I also tried

```
if (t.hasNext()) {
trim.add(t.next());
}

else {
t.close();
}
```

This iterates once and then returns the ArrayList, but I need to be able to input more. Changing my if or while condition to hasNextLine() gives the same results stated, here I used hasNext() because car trim levels have certain format expectations. I do not understand why hasNext() will not return as false when no input is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thank you! I understand why this works, but I suppose the root of my question is how hasNext() is operating in my loop if it does not detect when there is no input.

It.. doesn't.

Think about it. How can the computer tell the difference between a user who is thinking about what to type and perhaps leaving it for after lunch, and a user who is 'done'? Fire up the webcam and do some AI analysis of whether the user *looks* like they feel they are done with typing?

`System.in` **is not the keyboard**. It's the 'standard input for the JVM process' which is *by default*, at least, if you fire up a java app from the command line, set up to read from the keyboard. It does not have to be:

```
java -jar myapp.jar </some/path/to/some/file.txt
```

Now `System.in` reads from that file. There is no way to read from the keyboard for that process.

```
java -jar myapp.jar </dev/barcodeScanner1
```

Now presumably anytime you scan a barcode, the java app receives that as if you typed the numbers of that barcode in and hit 'enter'<sup>1</sup>.

It is up to the 'source of this input' to 'end'. A file ends when you get to the end of the file.

**A keyboard cannot possibly 'end'** - therefore, **`.hasNext()` cannot possibly return `false`**.

### Whitespace

You talk in your comments about 'entering whitespace'.

Then you don't understand `Scanner`. You're in good company; it's probably the most misunderstood thing. Certifiably so if we go by the sheer amount of questions StackOverflow is inundated with.

`Scanner` has **nothing** to do with keyboards.

Scanner just takes any source of textual input and splits it up into chunks. A chunk is called a 'token', and a 'token' is defined by 'all the text that is in between delimiters'. Delimiters are in turn defined by a regular expression, and *by default* the regex used is `\s+`. As in, any amount of whitespace.

Hence:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (true) {
    System.out.println("Token: ≥" + s.next()) + "≤");
  }
}
```

If you ran that, and entered on the command line, say: `hello world!`, then pressed enter, and typed `my name is Lajos`, you would see:

```
Token: ≥hello≤
Token: ≥world!≤
Token: ≥my≤
Token: ≥name≤
Token: ≥is≤
Token: ≥Lajos≤
```

The thing about scanner: It is **not possible** to register or otherwise get a bead on what the content of anything that falls under 'delimiter' is. You can't ask a scanner: How much whitespace was there?

You also can't ask: Please 'stop' when you encounter whitespace. No, whitespace simply separates one token from the next. There is, to a scanner, **no difference at all** between hitting enter, and hitting space and *then* enter. That's both '1 or more whitespace characters', so, interchangible, and as this is about the delimiter, undetectable.

You probably don't want to use Scanner at all. System.in itself certainly can differentiate it.

### Solution 1

The usual strategy is to mention in a prompt some magic word that indicates 'done'. For example:

```
static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  var s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Welcome to the fruit stand! Enter the fruit you'd like to buy, one at a time:");

  var basket = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (true) {
    System.out.print("Fruit (type 'DONE' when done): ");
    String fruit = s.next();
    if (fruit.equalsIgnoreCase("DONE")) break;
    basket.add(fruit);
  }

  System.out.println("Here's your basket: " + basket);
}
```

### Solution 2

Ditch scanner. Or at least, ditch all it is about and use only `nextLine`, which interacts *very* badly with all the other methods it has - choose one and only one (`nextLine`, or everything but `nextLine`):

```
static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  var s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Welcome to the fruit stand! Enter the fruit you'd like to buy, one at a time:");

  var basket = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (true) {
    System.out.print("Fruit (enter when done): ");
    String fruit = s.nextLine();
    if (fruit.isEmpty()) break;
    basket.add(fruit);
  }

  System.out.println("Here's your basket: " + basket);
}
```

---

[1] In practice most barcode scanners look and act like keyboards, and don't have a device in the sense that it does not exist in `/dev` / cannot be piped into a process like this. But, as an example, it works.

Comment: Great information! The solution I came to is similar to your attached solution 1. My question definitely came from a misunderstanding of what "next" is looking for. My next misunderstanding is how these solutions are not using a scanner, or what the difference between your scanner and my scanner is.

Comment: solution 2 uses only `nextLine` and nothing else. Which is fine. Solution 1 uses only `next`, and could use any of the other `next` methods other than `nextLine` - it could use `nextInt()` for example. As long as it never calls `nextLine`, also fine. What you can't do is call both on a single source. Well, you can do that, but what happens is bizarre. It's what the spec says should happen, but the spec is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static ArrayList getTrim() {

Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter car trim");
ArrayList<String> trim = new ArrayList<>();

while (t.hasNext()) {

if (!t.next().trim().equals("") {

trim.add(t.next());
      }

else {
t.close();
      }
   }

return trim;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand why this works, but I suppose the root of my question is how hasNext() is operating in my loop if it does not detect when there is no input. Does hasNext() need other conditions to return as false?

Comment: @kergil, the hasNext() method will go to the next input whenever an input has been received. No matter how the input is (if it's null, whitespace, or not null), the hasNext() will NOT return any false boolean statement if you write an input to the console.

Comment: if you want to ensure that no whitespace is entered, you should add custom configurations to your code: if(!t.next().trim().equals("")) { }

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
boolean notEmpty = true;
while (notEmpty && t.hasNext()) {
    String next = t.next().trim();
    if (notEmpty = (!next.isEmpty())) trim.add(next);
}
```

We have a boolean value to mark the cycle to end if we received whitespace only. Inside the loop, we get the (trimmed) next element and, if it's not empty (we update `notEmpty` inside the condition), then we add next.

Comment: Thank you! How does String.empty(next) operate? I thought for something like this next.isEmpty() would give the desired results. I also think I made a mistake in using "trim" for a Java question. Trim, here, is a specification for a real-life car (what I am modeling overall), I do not need to trim any strings! Also, where does the notEmpty boolean update?

Comment: @kgil well, trim has two meanings here, first, it's your arraylist, second, it's a method of Java that removes whitespaces at the start and the end of a string. After removing these whitespaces, if the string becomes of length of 0, i.e., if it's empty, then it contained only whitespaces and we should completely ignore it. Otherwise we can add it. "I do not need to trim any strings" you need to detect somehow whether your string is whitespace-only. I did not infer the use of `trim` from your naming, but from the fact that I wanted to remove whitespaces at start and end of string where they

Comment: @kgil are meaningless. So, while Trim is your real-life car model, I still use `trim` in the code to handle your attributes. Not because the name of Trim that you used, but for technical reasons. "Also, where does the notEmpty boolean update?" Inside the `if` conditional: `if (notEmpty = (!String.empty(next)))`. After we trimmed `next` in the previous line, we check whether it's empty, negate its result, assign this negated result to `notEmpty` and evaluate `notEmpty` logically.